# Difference between two times in HH:MI:SS

Tags: datetime, time, business-objects

**My Question:** I need to get the difference between two dates (times) in the format **HH:MI:SS** using a script. For example if I had two times:

```
2012/08/24 13:04:23
2012/08/24 14:15:32
```

My result would be:

```
1:11:09
```

**Requirements:** I'm writing this using SAP's BusinessObjects Data Services Designer, so my script must satisfy their syntax rules (click [here](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir32SP1/en/xi321_ds_designer_en.pdf) to see long PDF document... If you're not familiar with SAP's syntax, just know that it's really limited...).

---

**What I've tried:** Currently I have a function (see below) which will give the user a SQL statement they can use in the `SQL` function which will give them what they're looking for, but I would like to make this data store agnostic.

Here's my current function (not really what I'm looking for):

```
#Use this with a SQL function. For example: SQL('DSS_USER', GetTimeDifferenceSQL($time_1, $time_2));

return '
with seconds as (
  select 24*60*60*(to_date(\'[$time_1]\', \'YYYY.MM.DD hh24:mi:ss\')
                    - to_date(\'[$time_2]\', \'YYYY.MM.DD hh24:mi:ss\')) seconds_diff 
  from dual
)
select to_char(trunc(sum(seconds_diff)/3600), \'FM999999990\')  || \':\' || to_char(trunc(mod(sum(seconds_diff),3600)/60), \'FM00\') || \':\' || to_char(mod(sum(seconds_diff),60), \'FM00\')
from seconds
';
```

That doesn't work because I want this to stand alone from a data store and be calculated in the script alone.

I've also tried converting the dates into decimal numbers and then using the `JED_Time(int)` function on them, and that works, except decimal is base 10 and time is base whatever... So that won't work.

---

**My Hold-up:** I'm having a hard time with the fact that time doesn't really have a defined base.... Any help would be really great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not be totally accurate, but I think I got it. Input is more than welcome. Hopefully this will help someone one day!

```
#Make sure that when we're finding the difference, we always take the lesser date from the greater date. We'll negate it at the end.
if ($time_1 < $time_2)
begin
  $temp_time = $time_1;
  $time_1 = $time_2;
  $time_2 = $temp_time;
end

#Get all value differences from the two times
$nanoseconds = to_decimal(to_char($time_1, 'FF'), '.', null, 0) - to_decimal(to_char($time_2, 'FF'), '.', null, 0);
$seconds = to_decimal(to_char($time_1, 'SS'), '.', null, 0) - to_decimal(to_char($time_2, 'SS'), '.', null, 0);
$minutes = to_decimal(to_char($time_1, 'MI'), '.', null, 0) - to_decimal(to_char($time_2, 'MI'), '.', null, 0);
$hours = to_decimal(to_char($time_1, 'HH24'), '.', null, 0) - to_decimal(to_char($time_2, 'HH24'), '.', null, 0);
$days = interval_to_char($time_1 - $time_2, 'D');

#fix nanoseconds
if ($nanoseconds >= 1000000000)
begin
  $seconds = $seconds + 1;
  $nanoseconds = $nanoseconds - 1000000000;
end

if ($nanoseconds < 0)
begin
  $seconds = $seconds -1;
  $nanoseconds = $nanoseconds + 1000000000;
end

#fix seconds
if ($seconds >= 60)
begin
  $minutes = $minutes + 1;
  $seconds = $seconds - 60;
end

if ($seconds < 0)
begin
  $minutes = $minutes -1;
  $seconds = $seconds + 60;
end

#fix minutes
if ($minutes >= 60)
begin
  $hours = $hours + 1;
  $minutes = $minutes - 60;
end

if ($minutes < 0)
begin
  $hours = $hours -1;
  $minutes = $minutes + 60;
end

#fix hours
if ($hours >= 24)
begin
  $days = $days + 1;
  $hours = $hours - 24;
end

if ($hours < 0)
begin
  $days = $days - 1;
  $hours = $hours + 24;
end

#fix days
if (trunc($days/365, 0) >= 1)
begin
  $years = trunc($days/365, 0);
  $days = $days - ($years * 365);
end

if (round($days/7, 0) > 0)
begin
  $weeks = round($days/7, 0);
  $days = $days - ($weeks * 7);
end

$ret = '';

if ($years > 0)
begin
  $ret = $years||' year'||ifthenelse($years = 1, '', 's')||' ';
end

if ($weeks > 0)
begin
  $ret = $ret||$weeks||' week'||ifthenelse($weeks = 1, '', 's')||' ';
end

if ($days > 0)
begin
  $ret = $ret||$days||' day'||ifthenelse($days = 1, '', 's')||' ';
end

$ret = $ret||$hours||':'||lpad($minutes, 2, '0')||':'||lpad($seconds, 2, '0')||':'||lpad(round($nanoseconds/1000000, 0), 3, '0');

#Negate it if the parameter values were swapped at the beginning (using $temp_time)
if ($temp_time is not null)
begin
  $ret = '-'||$ret;
end

return $ret;
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier method would be to use the data type Interval.

To get the seconds between two datetimes:

```
interval_to_char( $dtFrom - $dtTo , 'SS');
```

> Takes an interval and returns a character representation of the interval.
>
> interval_to_char( [in] InputInterval As interval, [in] FormatString As varchar ) As varchar

This function could also be used to get minutes and hours.

Comment: First answer review: Can you please update this post to include a link to the reference you are citing?